# In Scala, is it possible to use curried arguments in other parameters?

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala. Pardon for the potentially stupid question. So I have this curried function. Is it possible to call the other parameters at invocation time?

```
def foo(a: Int)(b: Int): Int = a + b
```

And I want to invoke something like this and use the first argument on

```
foo(_)(_ - 1)
```

or something like this.

```
foo(_)(${0} - 5)
```

Comment: What does ${0} mean? Is it meaning accessing the first parameter?

Comment: @wqlin yes, that's correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When defining the method, it is possible to give the 2nd parameter a default value that references the 1st.

```
def foo(a: Int)(b: Int = a-1): Int = a + b

foo(9)()  //res0: Int = 17
foo(9)(1) //res1: Int = 10
```

Or you could create a method that wraps around `foo` to get what you want.

```
def fooWrapper(x: Int) = foo(x)(x-1)

fooWrapper(4)  //res0: Int = 7
```

Comment: Does this also apply to objects? Like `def foo(a: Fish)(b: Fish = Fish.parent)`

Comment: Your proposed code works, of course, but in that case the default value of `b` is unrelated to the value of `a`. If `Fish` is an `object`, i.e. a singleton, then the value of `Fish.parent` won't be different for different values of `a: Fish`.